# Problema con ready en Javascript y Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, django

Buenas, es en un desarrollo que incluye un menú de bootstrap y quería que dejara marcado que opción esta seleccionada, para ello uso un javascript.

Estaba funcionando correctamente hasta que he añadido alguna opción mas de menu, y es cuando he visto que en algunos casos, ni pasa por el script.

No acabo de entender la diferencia entre una opción y otra de menu, os pego en el que aparecen las opciones de menu y el script que uso.

Me funcionan bien conductores y empresas, pero en la opción de documentación ya no funciona el script, ni si quiera pasa por el, al igual que el primer localhost, y el segundo localhost, que apunta a una url distinta, pasa por el script pero no lo marca como "active"

Está desarrollado en django, no veo que el problema este ahí, pero quizas este equivocado, si necesitais que aporte código de django, solo hay que pedirlo.

¡Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo!

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('principio');
 $('li.active').removeClass('active');
 $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
    alert('final');
});
</script>
```

---

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/accounts/"">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/datos/listar-empresas/">Empresas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/datos/listar-conductores/">Conductores<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/francia/listar-certificados-francia/">Documentación<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/francia/listar-certificados-francia/">Localhost<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
                                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/francia/listar-certificados-francia-backend">Localhost<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Si en alguna de las páginas no te ejecuta el `script`, el problema puede ser que no lo estás incluyendo en el `html`, ¿lo has comprobado?

Comment: El problema parece ser que añades el trailing slash (/) al final de los enlaces, el navegador por defecto lo va a eliminar, de modo que te quede por ejemplo: `/francia/listar-certificados-francia`. Entonces, al seleccionar el link con esta URL no va a retornar nada porque **no existe**. Elimina el slash del final de las URLs y debe funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Gracias a todos, parece que el problema está resuelto, me puse a revisar la pagina que no funcionaba, tal y como me aconsejaba @Adrian Menendez y descubrí que tenía mal un id de una tabla que usa datatables, en eso no me había fijado. Al corregir ese error, empezó a funcionar el script de marcar los enlaces como active. Por lo que entiendo que se estaba haciendo un lío en otro lado el javascript, y por eso no llegaba a cargar el script en marcar los enlaces.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto @CecilioAlonso. Estaría bien que publicases tu solución como respuesta y la aceptases, de esa manera puede servir como futura referencia para otra persona y la pregunta no parece que esté aún sin resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente la solución pasó por ver detenidamente el código de la pagina en la que la opción de menú no funcionaba.

Debí darme cuenta cuando ejecutaba los alert en una opciones si y en otras no...

La pagina tenía ademas del código que he puesto, una tabla con un id que no le correspondia, pero ejecutaba un javascript de un datatable asociado a ese id.

El caso es que ese javascript mal asociado al id de la tabla, generaba un error y paraba la ejecución del resto de javascript, por eso no llegaba al alert, ni al código que marcaba como active.

Por lo que el script en si estaba bien, mal por mi parte que al copiar y pegar un trozo de código de una tabla, al no revisarlo bien, pasan estas cosas.

Gracias a todos por las respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo pondria dos event handler y quitaria ese codigo.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('li').on('mouseenter', '.deselection', function(){
      $(this).addClass('.selection').removeClass('.deselection');
   });

   $('li').on('mouseleave', '.selection', function(){
      $(this).addClass('.deselection').removeClass('.selection);
   });
});
```

No olvides etiquetar por defecto todos los 'li' con la clase .deselection que quieras hacer interactivos. Mas adecuado hover, selection, que active, ya que se supone que es pasar por encima el cursor, no?

Mi primera respuesta en stackoverflow que te hecho con mucho corazon, aunque no he probado el codigo espero que funcione y al menos te oriente. Ahms, creo que hay un metodo llamado hover con javascript que tambien haria lo mismo, quizas mas simple.

Comment: Me parece que no has entendido la pregunta. Lo que hace el código que tú le sugieres quitar, es detectar el `location` y marcar en el menú la posición que se corresponde, sin embargo tu código (no lo he probado), parece marcar la opción que tienes debajo del puntero del ratón.